# GM_xmlhttpRequest success callback 'onload' not executing for injected code

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

I am new to greasemonkey script, I am trying to make a POST request using GM_xmlhttpRequest but on success my onload function is not executing.

I know that GM_ functions do not work for injected code so I exported them to unsafeWindow.

Below is the code which I am injected into the page (although code is very long, I am pasting only relevant part).

```
function localGMCode(window, unsafeWindow) {
    window.GMUtils = {
        injectFunctionsIntoPage: function () {
            var gmInjectFuncs = {
                GMxmlhttpRequest: function(object) { return GM_xmlhttpRequest(object); },
            };
            if ((typeof createObjectIn !== 'undefined') && (typeof exportFunction !== 'undefined')) {
                var injectedGM = createObjectIn(unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "unsafeObj"});
                exportFunction(gmInjectFuncs.GMxmlhttpRequest, injectedGM, {defineAs: "GMxmlhttpRequest" });
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        GMxmlhttpRequest: function(object) {
            console.log(object);
            if (typeof GM_xmlhttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
                return GM_xmlhttpRequest(object);
            } else if (typeof iGraphHelperGM !== 'undefined') {
                return iGraphHelperGM.GMxmlhttpRequest(object);
            }
            return null;
        },
    };

    window.WikiSnapshot = {
        uploadDataToS3: function(snapshotUrl , iGraphUrl) {
            try {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    GMUtils.GMxmlhttpRequest({
                        method : 'POST',
                        url: <some url>,
                        onload: function(response){
                            console.log("Inside onload of GM_xmlhttpRequest");
                        },
                    });
                },0);
            } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        },
    };
}
```

In above code when ever GMxmlhttpRequest is getting completed, onload function is not executing, (I have already tried onerror , onreadystagechane and other callback function, issue is something else).

Below is the code which is injecting above mention code in page.

```
function injectMainIGraphHelper() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('(' + localGMCode + ');'));
    (document.body || document.head).appendChild(script);
}
```

I am running this on Firefox 38.6.0 , Greasemonkey 3.6
Please let me know if any more information is needed to debug this.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you can't inject GM_api to page and expected it'll run normally. Because all GM_api is implemented in sandbox, which is not available in page's context.

You either rewrite a GM_api-free script like any regular page script ( might not as hard as you thought, only cross-domain XMLHttpRequest is GM exclusive feature, all other GM_api will be easy to implement, especially we got all of those HTML5 features now.)

Or you let the script run in GM's sandbox, which will manage to get most jobs done in fact, the only thing you can't do is to modify an object or variables on page like the usual manner, you need add one grant metablock:

`//@grant unsafeWindow`

then let say there is a variable A=1 in page.

`var usw=unsafeWindow||window;
console.log(usw.A);//1`

Comment: Rewriting whole script again without any GM_ api is not possible as its very big script (around 7.1K lines) which is serving so many purposes, I pasted only relevant, and other then GM_xmlhttpRequest all other GM_ api are working perfectly fine after injecting them in Page. 
Due to cross domain call only I am using GM_xmlhttpRequest, else .ajax would solve the issue. Example which you provided is not relevant in above question's context.

Comment: it's relevant. if you have to use GM_xmlhttprequest, you use it in GM sandbox, then you will need unsafeWindow if you gonna access the page variables. You can't just insert a script node to the page and hoping GM_xmlhttprequest work. I doubt have you ever written a userscript... using `(document.body || document.head).appendChild(script);` to inject a GM_api code, which never works. Why you just start with a more simple one, instead of the 7k line code you copy from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your update, and thanks for your doubt also.. But I also doubt that have you ever read my code or not... Because I clearly mentioned function which I injected to unsafeWindow also.. With the help of this function only I am able to call GM_xmlhttpRequest API... I hope you understood the code...